# How to reference the generic type of a member of an inner class?

Tags: java, generics, nested, inner-classes, type-erasure

I'm curious to understand why `testInnerClass` fails to compile, citing:

> incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String.

```java
import java.util.List;

class Test<
        I extends Test.InnerClass,
        S extends Test.StaticInnerClass,
        O extends OtherClass> {

    void testOtherClass(O other) {
        String firstString = other.strings.get(0); //this works
    }
    
    void testStaticInnerClass(S staticInner) {
        String firstString = staticInner.strings.get(0); //this works
    }
    
    void testInnerClass(I inner) {
        String firstString = inner.strings.get(0); //this fails:
        //"incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String" 
    }

    static class StaticInnerClass {
        List<String> strings;
    }
    
    class InnerClass {
        List<String> strings;
    }
}

class OtherClass {
    List<String> strings;
}
```

`testStaticInnerClass` and `testOtherClass` work as I would expect but I'm not exactly sure why `testInnerClass` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InnerClass` is an inner class of `Test` which expects generic parameters.
So you need to update the class declaration as:

```java
class Test<
        I extends Test<I,S,O>.InnerClass,
        S extends Test.StaticInnerClass,
        O extends OtherClass>
```

The `StaticInnerClass`, even though inside `Test`, it is declared `static`.So as every `static` method or variable, the `static` class also does not depend on any state of the class. Hence it is not required to have `S extends Test<I,S,O>.StaticInnerClass`

Comment: Based on OP recent update new solution would be `Test<I extends Test<I,S,O>.InnerClass, ...>`. Anyway more info about the issue: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321)

Comment: Aha! Thanks Gautham for the clear, concise answer.